# Fedora 25 and disabling whatever is listening on port 111

Tags: networking, fedora, systemd

I've got a Fedora 25 x86_64 stand alone workstation. Something is listening on port 111 (identified with an nmap scan):

```
$ sudo lsof -i :111
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
systemd   1 root   36u  IPv4  15170      0t0  TCP *:sunrpc (LISTEN)
systemd   1 root   37u  IPv4  15171      0t0  UDP *:sunrpc
systemd   1 root   38u  IPv6  15172      0t0  TCP *:sunrpc (LISTEN)
systemd   1 root   39u  IPv6  15173      0t0  UDP *:sunrpc
```

I disabled the Sun gear on the port with the following commands:

```
$ sudo systemctl disable rpcbind
$ sudo systemctl disable sunrpc
Failed to disable unit: No such file or directory
```

After reboot the port is still open.

It appears something other than Sun gear wants to listen on port 111. Or maybe `systemd` is not respecting my wishes to disable the unused service. Or maybe something else...

How do I determine what is trying to listen on the port, and how do I disable it?

---

From below:

```
$ sudo systemctl -a | grep -E "rpc|port"
  var-lib-nfs-rpc_pipefs.mount          loaded    active   mounted   RPC Pipe File System
  abrtd.service                         loaded    active   running   ABRT Automated Bug Reporting Tool
  auth-rpcgss-module.service            loaded    inactive dead      Kernel Module supporting RPCSEC_GSS
  fedora-import-state.service           loaded    active   exited    Import network configuration from initramfs
  fedora-readonly.service               loaded    active   exited    Configure read-only root support
  rpc-gssd.service                      loaded    inactive dead      RPC security service for NFS client and server
  rpc-statd-notify.service              loaded    inactive dead      Notify NFS peers of a restart
  rpc-statd.service                     loaded    inactive dead      NFS status monitor for NFSv2/3 locking.
● rpc-svcgssd.service                   not-found inactive dead      rpc-svcgssd.service
  rpcbind.service                       loaded    inactive dead      RPC Bind
  rpcbind.socket                        loaded    active   listening RPCbind Server Activation Socket
  rpc_pipefs.target                     loaded    active   active    rpc_pipefs.target
  rpcbind.target                        loaded    active   active    RPC Port Mapper
```

Answer (score 12):

When you run `sudo systemctl disable rpcbind` on `Fedora 25` I think there is a warning:

```
Warning: Stopping rpcbind.service, but it can still be activated by:
rpcbind.socket
```

So you can try following:

```
sudo systemctl stop rpcbind.socket
sudo systemctl disable rpcbind.socket
```

Comment: I didn't see that message when I was testing it myself.  I think the problem is rpcbind.service isn't enabled or started in the first place (by default, and unless it gets activated)?  So it sees the service is already disabled, and terminates before reaching the message.  Should probably be improved.

Comment: Correction:  I didn't see that message because I only ran `disable`.  The message only appears on `stop` (and it does appear if the service is already stopped).  I can still empathize but I'm not sure what the best way to improve this experience would be.

Answer (score 8):

It is socket activation :).  And you were right to be suspicious.

You need to disable `rpcbind.socket`.  Disabling `rpcbind.service` - which is what `systemctl disable rpcbind` assumes - has no effect.

Also, the `disable` here will only affect what happens at boot time.  So if you want to see an immediate change, you *also* want to run `systemctl stop rpcbind.socket`.

EDIT: [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241444/why-is-init-listening-on-port-80?rq=1) looks very similar to me.  Jeff Schaller points out you can use the command `systemctl list-sockets`, to see the ports and services which `systemd` is implementing socket activation for.

---

I went back and had a look at `Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-25-1.3.iso`.

The status of rpcbind.service shows `indirect; vendor preset; disabled`. (Also `Active: inactive (dead)`). So it's clear disabling (or stopping) it again would not change anything.

I guess the `indirect` here is a hint to look out for other units which activate this one (including but not limited to socket units).  Once the socket unit is stopped as well, it changes from `indirect` to `disabled`.

The strange part is that the *socket* unit shows as `enabled; vendor preset: disabled`. This means something has enabled rpcbind.socket in the Fedora 25 image, but it was not enabled by `/lib/systemd/system-preset/80-workstation.preset` or `90-default.preset`. This appears to go against the (current) policy at https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:DefaultServices which is linked to from 90-default.preset -

> If the service should be enabled by default, it must be added to one of the distribution presets files.

This has been resolved at some point. `rpcbind.socket` is no longer enabled in `Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-28-1.1.iso`.

(This does not mean that rpcbind / port 111 is automatically accessible from the network on systems installed from a Fedora 25 disk. The install also includes a [firewall](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/443261/which-ports-does-the-default-firewall-allow-on-fedora-workstation-and-fedora-ser) which does not allow port 111)

Comment: Thanks @sourcejedi. Disabling `sunrpc` and `rpcbind` did not stop the listener.

Comment: @jww _You need to disable rpcbind.socket. Disabling rpcbind.service does nothing._

Comment: Thanks @sourcejedi. I've got to get to work so I don't have time to dig into this deeper right now. You got my upvote. Why do people think its a good idea to break simple processes that have been around for years and always "just worked"... https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: Or [xkcd.com/1172](https://xkcd.com/1172/)

Comment: @jww Socket activation is one of my least unfavourite systemd features; it actually makes a lot of sense. (What doesn't make sense is for them to be classified separately to normal services)

Answer (score 7):

Port 111 is linked to to [portmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmap). If you use NFS chances are you will need it. You can use `systemctl -a | grep -E "rpc|port"` to see the name of the corresponding service and disable it (I don't have access to a Fedora box at the time).

Comment: Kind of noisy to look through - 13 lines of output, and the output suffers from not being able to access the tty directly.

Answer (score 1):

This port is activated by the `nfs` service, installed from the `nfs-utils` package. If you don't need it you'd better uninstall it. `nfs-utils` and `iscsi-initiator-utils` are usually installed as dependencies of `libvirt` package. Both packages activate a plenty of services and sockets you might not have wanted. This commands can be used in order to disable `nfs` and `iscsi-initiator-utils` services.

```
systemctl disable nfs-client.target
systemctl stop nfs-client.target
systemctl disable rpcbind.socket
systemctl stop rpcbind.socket
systemctl stop rpc_pipefs.target
systemctl stop rpcbind.target
systemctl stop rpcbind.service
systemctl disable rpcbind.service
systemctl stop var-lib-nfs-rpc_pipefs.mount
systemctl stop proc-fs-nfsd.mount 
systemctl disable gssproxy.service
systemctl stop gssproxy.service
modprobe -r sunrpc
systemctl disable iscsid.socket
systemctl stop iscsid.socket
systemctl disable iscsiuio.socket
systemctl stop iscsiuio.socket
systemctl disable iscsid.service
systemctl stop iscsid.service
systemctl disable iscsiuio.service
systemctl stop iscsiuio.service
```