How do I stop and close these processes listening on sunrpc port? Presumably for proper zfs operation
I have a zfs volume that is automounted at startup. Doing an lsof -i shows systemd pid 1 listening on the sunrpc port for tcp and udp. There's an rpc.mount and rpcbind that shows up as well during lsof -i but are on high ports. How do I stop these processes, assuming that I don't need zfs running any longer.
rpcbind shows up as a service in systemd. But rpc.mount and systemd listening on the sunrpc port 111 doesn't and I'm not sure how to stop these.

You can check this answer which shows it's linked to rpcbind.socket or rpcbind.target https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369937/fedora-25-and-disabling-whatever-is-listening-on-port-111

That's a great answer, but it seems like a strange way to design a system where systemd itself is listening to an open socket and not have an immediate systemctl command to get it to stop. Referring to the rmmod of the sunrpc kernel module.

systemd is a strange way to design a system.  D.

I don't like it that systemd is listening on a port, and there's no real way of directly telling systemd to not do that. And that the only reason to guess at it's function is the port it binds to is a well known sunrpc port. If systemd is functioning like a portmapper, then shouldn't there be systemd commands to stop this binding on the CLI?
