# Weird init process listening on TCP port 53, LinuxMint Victoria

Tags: linux, networking, dns

When I run `netstat -nptl`, I have this weird output:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.2.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/init
```

This is from `dnscrypt-proxy`'s DoH service with default configuration.

```
ps uww 1
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root           1  0.1  0.0 166580 11936 ?        Ss   12:15   0:01 /sbin/init splash
```

I wonder why PID 1, makes no sense now

Comment: Port 53 is the default DNS port. What are you exactly doing when you say you are changing the default ISP DNS resolvers?  Are you running a local DNS server?

Comment: Modifying /etc/resolv.conf. I know this is the regular DNS port, but more often used with UDP

Comment: Yes, I run dnscrypt-proxy, and this is this service using this weird netstat output

Comment: DNS can use either TCP or UDP, and the port is the same for both.  The fact that you are using `dnscrypt-proxy` is not an uninteresting fact. You should add that to the question along with the relevant configuration (like, what port it's listening on).

Comment: dnscrypt-proxy is a DoH service

Comment: Can we assume that you have read [the documentation](https://github.com/DNSCrypt/dnscrypt-proxy/wiki/Installation-linux) and that you are on Debian?

Comment: There's nothing I've found in the documentation about my question. And yes, I follow the doc

Comment: You seem to have two questions:  "What is listening to `127.0.2.1:53`?" The answer to that is in the documentation of `dnscrypt-proxy` (it is `dnscrypt-proxy` with its default configuration on Debian), and "Why is `init` PID 1?" or possibly "Why is `dnsscrypt-proxy` seemingly PID 1?" (it's unclear what makes no sense to you).

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241444/why-is-init-listening-on-port-80

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Linux using `netstat` should be replaced by using `ss`, because it provides more information. For this case it provides *all* processes sharing the socket, while `netstat` stops at the first. There are other minor differences such as providing the `comm` name (`systemd`) instead of the `cmd` name (`init`). Here on Debian 12, but any systemd-based Linux system would be similar:

```shell
# netstat -tnlp | awk 'NR <=2 || /127.0.2.1:/'
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.2.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/init              
# ss -nptl src 127.0.2.1
State   Recv-Q  Send-Q   Local Address:Port     Peer Address:Port  Process  
LISTEN  0       4096         127.0.2.1:53            0.0.0.0:*      users:(("dnscrypt-proxy",pid=6245,fd=8),("systemd",pid=1,fd=49))
```

One can see that both `systemd` and `dnscrypt-proxy` share the same socket.

Why? Because `dnscrypt-proxy` is running though *systemd*'s [Socket](https://0pointer.de/blog/projects/socket-activation.html) [Activation](https://0pointer.de/blog/projects/socket-activation2.html): a mechanism similar to *inetd* but improved that allows (if configured so) to have a socket listening before having the daemon actually running, ready to start the daemon on first invocation. When a *systemd* [service configuration](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.service.html) has an associated *systemd* [socket configuration](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.socket.html) (with an adequate dependency, here `Requires=dnscrypt-proxy.socket`), that means it's using socket activation.

```shell
# systemctl status dnscrypt-proxy.socket 
* dnscrypt-proxy.socket - dnscrypt-proxy listening socket
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dnscrypt-proxy.socket; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-01-09 18:16:11 UTC; 23min ago
   Triggers: * dnscrypt-proxy.service
       Docs: https://github.com/DNSCrypt/dnscrypt-proxy/wiki
     Listen: 127.0.2.1:53 (Stream)
             127.0.2.1:53 (Datagram)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 18402)
     Memory: 12.0K
        CPU: 1ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/dnscrypt-proxy.socket

[...]
# systemctl status dnscrypt-proxy.service
* dnscrypt-proxy.service - DNSCrypt client proxy
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dnscrypt-proxy.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-01-09 18:38:54 UTC; 1min 20s ago
TriggeredBy: * dnscrypt-proxy.socket
       Docs: https://github.com/DNSCrypt/dnscrypt-proxy/wiki
   Main PID: 6245 (dnscrypt-proxy)
      Tasks: 12 (limit: 18402)
     Memory: 10.6M
        CPU: 60ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/dnscrypt-proxy.service
             `-6245 /usr/sbin/dnscrypt-proxy -config /etc/dnscrypt-proxy/dnscrypt-proxy.toml

[...]
```

The socket creation was handled directly by `systemd` through the `.socket` part associated to the `.service` part, and this listening socket was then inherited by `dnscrypt-proxy` (which has to be aware of this method).

There are various advantages with this method, among them at least these two (the others are described in [Socket](https://0pointer.de/blog/projects/socket-activation.html) [Activation](https://0pointer.de/blog/projects/socket-activation2.html) links):

- the daemon doesn't have to run with any privileges to open privileged ports, even at startup
- a daemon can choose to stop after a period of inactivity, thus freeing system resources. *systemd* will restart it if a new query is received, without having the system refuse a connection meanwhile.

Comment: Thanks. Is it new that `ss` have same basic arguments than `netstat` ? Nice

Comment: Very good example to understand why `ss` is better than deprecated `netstat`